# "term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments" error

Tags: c++

```
template <typename T>
    class Sorteermethode {
    public:
        virtual void operator()(vector<T> & v) const = 0;

        void meet(int kortste, int langste, ostream& os) {
            Sortvector<T> * mijnVector = new Sortvector<T>(kortste);
            Chrono * chrono = new Chrono;
            while (kortste <= langste) {
                (*mijnVector).vul_range();
                (*chrono).start();
                this()(*mijnVector);
                (*chrono).stop();
                printf("Lengte: %d tijd: %f", kortste, (*chrono).tijd());
                kortste *= 10;
                (*mijnVector).resize(kortste);
            }
            free(chrono);
            free(mijnVector);
        };
    };
```

When I try to call the earlier defined operator () I get the following error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C2064   term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments Algoritmen1 c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\algoritmen1\algoritmen1\sorteermethode.h    40
```

Could anyone give me some insight on this? As far as I can see it does not resolve to the function with one parameter.

Comment: Post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please.

Comment: Side note : use `delete` on objects created with `new`, not `free`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
this()(*mijnVector);
```

is attempting to call the `this` pointer. You want to call on the object it's pointing to. The correct syntax is:

```
(*this)(*mijnVector);
```

Or, if you're feeling particularly wordy:

```
this->operator()(*mijnVector);
```